# How to display fields from different entities in views

Tags: views

In my project, i need to create a view that displays fields created in the profile 2 module and a field from the core registration form (Username) in the same table. Please how can this be done? I plan to filter users using the username field. and other values provided via the profile 2 fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Start with either the base table of user entity or profile 2 entity, then just add a relationship in views to the other. It is found under the "advanced tab" in views.